# Why does the function "receive-from" in IOLib always throw an EWOULDBLOCK exception?

Tags: network-programming, io, lisp, common-lisp

```
(setf buf (make-array 1024 :element-type 'unsigned-byte))
(receive-from socket
              :buffer buf
              :start 0
              :end 1024))
```

No matter how many times I retry, it always throws `ewouldblock`, and reads nothing from the socket.  Why?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to set socket-stream to non-blocking state:

```
(setf (iolib.streams:fd-non-blocking connected-socket) t)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I've found the problem, I use set-io-handler() to monitor the read event of a socket, but the argument "function" was filled by just calling another function whose return value was not a function, so the function was always called when set-io-handler() was called, but in fact the socket wasn't ready yet, and also, the callback function of the read-event wasn't set correctly.

In addition, is there full documentation about IOLib? Now I can only read the source code of it, it's not so easy for a beginner...

Comment: There are 2 useful docs on IOLib: http://common-lisp.net/project/iolib/manual/ and http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~psilord/blog/data/iolib-tutorial/tutorial.html. Also I've heard Stellia Ionescu promising to create a more comprehensive docs.